# When user removes "Works with Nest" for my client, the "withCancelBlock" is not called

Tags: nest-api

I'm using the following code to get notified when the user revokes permission from my client.  Specifically, I expect the `withCanelBlock` to be called when the user revokes permission, but this block is never called.

```
        [newFirebase observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        [self.subscribedURLs setObject:snapshot forKey:URL];
        NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
        block(snapshot);
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%s: permission revoked!!!!!", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
     ];
```